# Вывести на печать два словаря разной длины

Tags: python, циклы, словари, dict

У меня есть два словаря different_a и different_b разной длины. Как мне вывести их оба на печать в следующем формате:

```
firstName-John              first_name-Alex
isAlive-True                isAlive-False
age-27                      Age-27
city-New York               city-Chicago
state-NY                    None
postalCode-10021-3100       None
```

Я использую следующий код:

```
    for (key, value), (key1, value1) in zip(different_a.items(), different_b.items()):
        print(("{0}-{1}\t\t\t\t{2}-{3}" .format(key, value, key1, value1)))
```

Но проблема в том, что когда ключ-значения в одном словаре заканчиваются, то и цикл прекращается, не давая возможности доитерировать другой более длинный словарь.

Comment: используйте `itertools.zip_longest()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `zip_longest`, но нужно указать параметр `fillvalue` (спасибо за напоминание SergFSM), чтобы у вас не сломалась распаковка параметров:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

different_a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
different_b = {'a': 4, 'b': 5}

for (key1, value1), (key2, value2) in zip_longest(different_a.items(), different_b.items(), fillvalue=(None, None)):
    print("{0}-{1}\t\t\t\t{2}-{3}" .format(key1, value1, key2, value2))
```

Вывод:

```
a-1             a-4
b-2             b-5
c-3             None-None
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Comment: если `zip_longest` указать параметр `fillvalue=(None,None)`  то можно сократить код на две строки (оставить вариант автора вопроса)

Comment: @SergFSM Спасибо, вечно забываю про параметры )

Answer (score 1):

немного изменил ваш код:

```
for items_a, items_b in zip_longest(different_a.items(), 
                                    different_b.items(), 
                                    fillvalue=(None,None)):
    print(("{}-{}\t\t\t\t{}-{}".format(*items_a,*items_b)))
```